# Why a dispatch to a reducer causes all reducers get called?

Tags: redux, react-redux

In this [github redux example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples), a dispatch of the event ADD_TODO is used to add a task. During the debugging, I found out that adding a task causes both the [reducers](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos/reducers) **todos** and **visibilityFilter** being called.

How can I call just the **todos** reducer and not **visibilityFilter** reducer when I add a task. Also the **visibilityFilter** reducer if I sent an event of type SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER.

Comment: I just cloned the repo and haven't modified anything. I have added a console.log for `SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER` action and `ADD_TODO`. When I add a task it does not log anything from `SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER` reducer

Comment: I did not use the console log, but debugged directly in Google chrome debugger. You can reproduce by (1) put breakpoints in both the reducers before the switch statement (2) go to the UI in the browser (http://locahost:3000 if you run the command npm start) and add a task, for example 'test task' in the edit box. You will see that both the reducers get breaks, but only the action in the todos reducer gets executed.

Comment: Isn't because `combineReducers()` parse the reducers and isnt actually executing them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `combineReducers` utility intentionally calls all attached reducer functions for every action, and gives them a chance to respond.  This is because the suggested Redux reducer structure is "reducer composition", where many mostly-independent reducer functions can be combined into one structure, and many reducer functions could potentially respond to a single action and update their own slice of state.

Comment: My concern is about [MapStateToProps](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/containers/VisibleTodoList.js) method which gets called for all the container components. In my case, I have 5 container components. When an action is dispatched, it should update only one container and not any of the child or sibling components. I see that the **MapStateToProps** function is called for all the 5 containers, and is wasting the resources. Is there a way I can prevent the **MapStateToProps** to be executed?

Comment: No.  You're misunderstanding the intent behind `mapStateToProps`, and how the React-Redux `connect()` function uses it.  Since there's a single state tree in Redux, any dispatched action _could_ have updated any part of the state, and there's only one subscription notification.  So, `connect()` re-runs _all_ subscribed MSTP functions, but then shallow-compares the results for each one to see if anything changed from the last call.  If the output for an MSTP is the same, the component is not re-rendered.  You _want_ MSTP to re-run each time.

Comment: I'm not using [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect). Still, what you described would work? That's not what I'm seeing in my code. There is no logic that prevent running the MSTP functions.

Comment: Feel like we're talking at cross-purposes here.  Recapping: 1) Using `combineReducers` automatically gives all sub-reducers a chance to respond to _every_ dispatched action, in case they're interested.  2) Using `connect()` _always_ calls _every_ connected component's `mapStateToProps` for _every_ dispatched action.  For each MSTP call, `connect()` then compares the new MSTP return value against the old MSTP return value, and if nothing changed, that component does not re-render. Why are you wanting to prevent MSTP from being called? That defeats the purpose of `connect()`.

Comment: I'm also confused how we got from the original question of "How do I only call a specific reducer for a specific action", to "How do I keep `mapStateToProps` from running".

Comment: The second point is what I'm struggling with. In my app, the MSTP for component A is called and the presentation component is re-rendered also (really, the **render** method is called). How I noticed this was that the UI has so much flickering which means the DOM gets manipulated. But there is not a state change for component A but there is a state change in a container for component B. Now you confirmed me about the expectation of **connect**, I will do little more testing and post the result here.

Comment: It seems like you're confusing a few different things here, but I don't have enough information and context to help. SO is telling me that extended conversations in comments are a bad idea.  I'd suggest asking for help in the Reactiflux chat channels on Discord - invite link is at https://www.reactiflux.com.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, combineReducers calls every reducer whenever a dispatch is called. You can avoid the other values changing, by making the default case equal to the state parameter passed in, so essentially they are reassigned their current value.
For example:

```
const individualReducer = (state = "initialState", action) => {
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case "ACTION_TYPE":
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default individualReducer;
```