# Redux with multiple reducers, forcing every dispatched action to go to its reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux

I use react + redux with multiple reducers.
I figured out that every dispatched action goes through every reducer, although there's only one relevant reducer for this action.
Is there an option to force every dispatched action to go only to its reducer?

If not - why? Surely I misunderstand something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why a dispatch to a reducer causes all reducers get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379904/why-a-dispatch-to-a-reducer-causes-all-reducers-get-called)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough points to mark it as such, but this looks like a duplicate, please see:

[Why a dispatch to a reducer causes all reducers get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379904/why-a-dispatch-to-a-reducer-causes-all-reducers-get-called)

[All reducers will be invoked when an action is dispatched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590579/all-reducers-will-be-invoked-when-an-action-is-dispatched)

**Short answe**r: it is normal and intended, there is no such option to prevent it because when you have a complex state tree, you should not have to care to compute and check what needs to be changed manually, this is the role of redux and unless you have a huge application, performance will not be an issue (reducers are often just simple multiple lines pure function).

If you are worried about performance, check out https://github.com/reactjs/reselect mentionned in one of the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Redux FAQ entry on "calling all reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-all-reducers), you really only have *one* root reducer function.  *If* you generated that root reducer using the built-in `combineReducers` function, then yes, it will always run all of the slice reducers you've provided for every dispatched action, because that's how `combineReducers` works.

If you want other behavior, you can write your own reducer logic for your specific use case.  See the [Redux docs section on "Structuring Reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) for more information on various ways to organize reducer logic.